# AWS S3 event notification on object permission change

Tags: amazon-s3

Can you some one guide me how to setup an event notification for object level permission change.Currently notification available for read,write,delete etc..
But I am looking to setup a email trigger if some one changed access permission in an s3 object inside a bucket.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to deal with this kind of concern:

1. Proactive: write [IAM policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/amazon-s3-policy-keys.html) that prevent users from putting object
   with public access
2. Reactive: use CloudWatch Events to detect issues and respond to them (see [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-detect-and-automatically-remediate-unintended-permissions-in-amazon-s3-object-acls-with-cloudwatch-events/))

Comment: Thanks for your response jarmod.I will go through the same and try to implement.